# i am trying to change the state of my component with this.SetState(), but its no working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Landingpage from './components/Landingpage';
import Mainbody from './components/Mainbody';
import './App.css';

import axios from 'axios';
import { FORTNITE_IO } from './config'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
      itemShop: {},
      test: 'damiisdandy'
    };

  getItemShop = () => 
    axios.get('https://fortniteapi.io/shop?lang=en', {
          headers: {
              Authorization: FORTNITE_IO
          }
      })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(err => err);
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({itemShop: this.getItemShop()})
    this.setState({test: 'feyi'})
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="sil">
            <img style={{ zIndex: 0 }} src="./img/glider-sil.png" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <Navbar />
        <Landingpage />
        <Mainbody />
        <footer>
            <img src="./img/midas3.png" alt="geng"/>
            <img className="footer-img" src="./img/midas1.png" alt="geng"/>
        </footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am new to react, 
i am making a request with axios and trying to update my state with the response data
I am trying to update the state with this.Setstate() but it doesn't seem to update the state at all.. please i need help!!!!!!

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code - but assuming that you're complaining about the `console.log` logging the old state, that's because `setState` is asynchronous. You can give it a callback function as a second argument, which will only be called when the state update actually takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing for you to do is to make the request , when the response comes in then you call set state . When you call componentDidMount and set state the request does not come in immediately.  So the best thing to do.

```
getItemShop = () => {
    axios.get('https://fortniteapi.io/shop?lang=en', {
          headers: {
              Authorization: FORTNITE_IO
          }
      })
      .then(res => {
           this.setState({itemShop: res.data})
      }
      .catch(err => err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `console.log(this.state)` and use the [React devtools extension](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions) to view state instead.

Comment: thanks.. i didn't know it was changing in the background!